# Is it possible to run a scheduled task each midnight in Shopware?

Tags: cron, shopware, shopware6

We have read https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-scheduled-task which described how to define a scheduled tasks which runs every x minutes.

Is it also possible to specific the execution time, for example each midnight or every day a 2 am, like in a crontab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a feature in Shopware core.
The probably most straightforward way would be to add a "real" cronjob like you mentioned, which triggers a CLI-command.
You can encapsulate the logic of the task in it's own service, so that the scheduled task and cli-command both can just use the service (if you want to keep both).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such possibility in Shopware 6. It is easier to accomplish this with a CLI command and crontab. But if you have to use Shopware's scheduled task then you can trick it by setting the `nextExecutionTime` to the time you want to execute the task.

For example if today's date is 10.03.2022 and you want to execute the scheduled task every day at 2 am then set the `nextExecutionTime` to `2022-03-11 00:02:00.000` (use future date) and `runInterval` to `86400` (24h). This way Shopware will start the task at 2 am and then set the `nextExecutionTime` to the next day at 2 am (+- couple of minutes from my experience).